# Manually create a table and automatically number its caption, word output

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, tabular

I'd like to display my table caption on top of a manually typed table. I'm using the following code but the caption does not show in the  knitted output. Please see how I could improve my code. Thank you and happy new year.

```
---
title:
author:
date:
output:
  word_document:
    toc: yes
  highlight: tango
documentclass: book
---

[Table: table name] 
| column 1 | column 2 | column 3|
| -------- | -------- | --------|
| 1 | a | b | 
| 2 | c | d |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc's syntax for tables is

```
: table name

| column 1 | column 2 | column 3|
| -------- | -------- | --------|
| 1 | a | b | 
| 2 | c | d |
```

This is how it looks like in Word:

[image: word output]

<sub>And belated happy new year to you too!</sub>